# What is client base class , how to use it?

Tags: wcf

I am just curious to know that what is ClientBase class in WCF, and how can i use it.
I surfed the internet and i found that this class is used to create proxies to call service methods , but no example.
Please anyone explain it with example , it will help me undestand this class...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the base class for your client proxies being generated by either "Add Service Reference", the `svcutil.exe` command line utility, or by your custom code if you don't want to use any of those methods.

It's a generic type that takes the generated client-copy of the service contract as its type parameter.

It can be extended, if you wish to do so - e.g. see IDesign's [download page](http://www.idesign.net/idesign/DesktopDefault.aspx?tabindex=5&tabid=11) for a few samples of what can be done, things like:

- **AsyncClientBase** for safe asynchronous calls
- **HeaderClientBase** for simplified support of custom headers in your messages

Marc

Answer (score 0):

It's there for autogenerated proxies which are created when service references are added to your project, not really for your own use.

Comment: can i extend it , i don't want to add service reference to create proxy.

Comment: No. If you don't want a created proxy then you should be using ChannelFactory<T> and sharing the interface and contract objects.